# tkinter list of labels not displaying properly

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm setting up a simple GUI to display the status of network ports.  If I use individual commands for each label, this works fine:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x225')
root.configure(background='white')
pFontsize = 10

p1 = Label(root, text = '1', background = 'white',font=('Calibri', pFontsize),anchor='center').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 1/14, rely = 2/10)
p2 = Label(root, text = '2', background = 'white',font=('Calibri', pFontsize),anchor='center').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 2/14, rely = 2/10)
p3 = Label(root, text = '3', background = 'white',font=('Calibri', pFontsize),anchor='center').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 3/14, rely = 2/10)
p4 = Label(root, text = '4', background = 'white',font=('Calibri', pFontsize),anchor='center').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 4/14, rely = 2/10)
p5 = Label(root, text = '5', background = 'white',font=('Calibri', pFontsize),anchor='center').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 5/14, rely = 2/10)
p6 = Label(root, text = '6', background = 'white',font=('Calibri', pFontsize),anchor='center').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 6/14, rely = 2/10)
p7 = Label(root, text = '7', background = 'white',font=('Calibri', pFontsize),anchor='center').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 7/14, rely = 2/10)
p8 = Label(root, text = '8', background = 'white',font=('Calibri', pFontsize),anchor='center').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 8/14, rely = 2/10)
p9 = Label(root, text = '9', background = 'white',font=('Calibri', pFontsize),anchor='center').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 9/14, rely = 2/10)
p10 = Label(root, text = '10', background = 'white',font=('Calibri', pFontsize),anchor='center').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 10/14, rely = 2/10)
p11 = Label(root, text = '11', background = 'white',font=('Calibri', pFontsize),anchor='center').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 11/14, rely = 2/10)
p12 = Label(root, text = '12', background = 'white',font=('Calibri', pFontsize),anchor='center').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 12/14, rely = 2/10)
p13 = Label(root, text = '13', background = 'white',font=('Calibri', pFontsize),anchor='center').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 1/14, rely = 5/10)
p14 = Label(root, text = '14', background = 'white',font=('Calibri', pFontsize),anchor='center').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 2/14, rely = 5/10)
p15 = Label(root, text = '15', background = 'white',font=('Calibri', pFontsize),anchor='center').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 3/14, rely = 5/10)
p16 = Label(root, text = '16', background = 'white',font=('Calibri', pFontsize),anchor='center').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 4/14, rely = 5/10)
p17 = Label(root, text = '17', background = 'white',font=('Calibri', pFontsize),anchor='center').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 5/14, rely = 5/10)
p18 = Label(root, text = '18', background = 'white',font=('Calibri', pFontsize),anchor='center').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 6/14, rely = 5/10)
p19 = Label(root, text = '19', background = 'white',font=('Calibri', pFontsize),anchor='center').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 7/14, rely = 5/10)
p20 = Label(root, text = '20', background = 'white',font=('Calibri', pFontsize),anchor='center').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 8/14, rely = 5/10)
p21 = Label(root, text = '21', background = 'white',font=('Calibri', pFontsize),anchor='center').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 9/14, rely = 5/10)
p22 = Label(root, text = '22', background = 'white',font=('Calibri', pFontsize),anchor='center').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 10/14, rely = 5/10)
p23 = Label(root, text = '23', background = 'white',font=('Calibri', pFontsize),anchor='center').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 11/14, rely = 5/10)
p24 = Label(root, text = '24', background = 'white',font=('Calibri', pFontsize),anchor='center').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 12/14, rely = 5/10)

i1 = Label(root, background = 'black').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 1/14, rely = 3/10)
i2 = Label(root, background = 'black').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 2/14, rely = 3/10)
i3 = Label(root, background = 'black').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 3/14, rely = 3/10)
i4 = Label(root, background = 'black').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 4/14, rely = 3/10)
i5 = Label(root, background = 'black').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 5/14, rely = 3/10)
i6 = Label(root, background = 'black').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 6/14, rely = 3/10)
i7 = Label(root, background = 'black').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 7/14, rely = 3/10)
i8 = Label(root, background = 'black').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 8/14, rely = 3/10)
i9 = Label(root, background = 'black').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 9/14, rely = 3/10)
i10 = Label(root, background = 'black').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 10/14, rely = 3/10)
i11 = Label(root, background = 'black').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 11/14, rely = 3/10)
i12 = Label(root, background = 'black').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 12/14, rely = 3/10)
i13 = Label(root, background = 'black').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 1/14, rely = 6/10)
i14 = Label(root, background = 'black').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 2/14, rely = 6/10)
i15 = Label(root, background = 'black').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 3/14, rely = 6/10)
i16 = Label(root, background = 'black').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 4/14, rely = 6/10)
i17 = Label(root, background = 'black').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 5/14, rely = 6/10)
i18 = Label(root, background = 'black').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 6/14, rely = 6/10)
i19 = Label(root, background = 'black').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 7/14, rely = 6/10)
i20 = Label(root, background = 'black').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 8/14, rely = 6/10)
i21 = Label(root, background = 'black').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 9/14, rely = 6/10)
i22 = Label(root, background = 'black').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 10/14, rely = 6/10)
i23 = Label(root, background = 'black').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 11/14, rely = 6/10)
i24 = Label(root, background = 'black').place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = 12/14, rely = 6/10)

root.mainloop()
```

[Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mdm1l.jpg)

However, when I create a class then set up a list to do the same thing, I only see one label displayed:

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.geometry('400x225')
#root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
root.configure(background='white')

class networkPort:
    numFontsize = 10
    num = Label(root, background = 'white',font=('Calibri', numFontsize),anchor='center')
    indicator = Label(root, background = 'black')
 
ports = []
for i in range(24):
    ports.append(networkPort)
    ports[i].num.configure(text = str(i+1))
    if i > 11:
        y = 4
    else:
        y = 2
    ports[i].num.place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = (i%12 + 1)/14, rely = y/10)
    ports[i].indicator.place(relwidth = 1/14, relheight = 1/10, relx = (i%12 + 1)/14, rely = y+1/10)

root.mainloop()
```

[Not Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Zjtx.jpg)

I'm fairly new to Python, so I'm quite confident it's something I'm doing wrong here.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You have used `class variables` instead of `instance variables`.  There is only one set of `class variables` for a class, so you overwrite the `class variables` in each iteration.  Suggest to go through tutorials on Python OOP.

Comment: Yep, I figured something like that was happening when I added a delay to the loop and saw the same label getting redrawn in each location.  The last time I wrote anything with OOP was Borland Turbo Pascal over 30 years ago, so you're right I definitely need to read up.  Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used *`class variables`* instead of *`instance variables`*. There is only one set of *`class variables`* for a class, so you overwrite the *`class variables`* in each iteration.

Below is an example of using *`instance variables`*:

```py
class NetworkPort:
    def __init__(self, master, num):
        numFontsize = 10
        self.num = Label(master, text=num, background='white', font=('Calibri', numFontsize), anchor='center')
        self.indicator = Label(master, background='black')

ports = []
for i in range(24):
    ports.append(NetworkPort(root, i+1))
    y = 4 if i > 11 else 2
    ports[i].num.place(relwidth=1/14, relheight=1/10, relx=(i%12+1)/14, rely=y/10)
    ports[i].indicator.place(relwidth=1/14, relheight=1/10, relx=(i%12+1)/14, rely=(y+1)/10)
```

Comment: Yep, works perfectly.  Also, I wasn't aware that Python allows that particular if..else syntax.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to adjust it so you maintain the original proportions of the GUI under a class based structure:

```
from tkinter import *


class NetworkPort:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.geometry('400x225')
        master.configure(background='white')
        self.num_font_size = 10
        
        # List to be populated with indicator widgets
        self.widgets = []

        x = -1
        y = 0

        for i in range(24):

            # On 12 iteration move to new line (y), reset to first column (x)
            if i == 12:
                x = 0
                y = 3

            # Move to new column with each iteration
            else:
                x += 1

            # Generate network port number
            num = Label(master, background='white', text=i + 1, font=('Calibri', self.num_font_size), anchor='center')
            num.place(relwidth=1 / 14, relheight=1 / 10, relx=(x + 1) / 14, rely=(y + 2) / 10)

            # Generate network indicator label
            indicator = Label(master, background='black')
            indicator.place(relwidth=1 / 14, relheight=1 / 10, relx=(x + 1) / 14, rely=(y + 3) / 10)

            # Add indicator label objects to list
            self.widgets.append(indicator)

        # Example of adjusting one specific indicators colour by accessing the widget list
        self.widgets[3].config(bg='red')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    NetworkPort(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Hopefully that helps, feel free to query anything you're curious about.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Much cleaner code :-)  However, I actually require a list of classes, because in later code each instance will need to be addressed individually by index, eg: to ping, change the background to green/red, then perform specific API calls to reconfigure the specific device attached to each port, based on subsequent QR code input and predefined lookup tables.

Comment: To troubleshoot, I added time.sleep(0.5) and root.update() in between each place command.  It turns out each label actually displays, then disappears as soon as the next place is executed.  So, even though I'm appending a new class instance to the list, it appears to be referencing the same Label object every time???

Comment: You can directly reference the individual tkinter elements added in the `for i in range(24):` by adding the objects to a  list as opposed to creating a list of classes. You can either use `winfo_children` for all objects or, since i imagine you want to just update the indicator labels, create a widget list of just those. I've updated my code to show how you'd update the colour of a single indicator label as an example.

Comment: Understood, and thanks for the updated code.  I agree, if all I was trying to do was implement this on-screen representation, it's a far better way to do it.  However this is not the whole class definition, only the portion which applies to the GUI.  there's a bunch of socket connections, and other things that need to happen individually for each instance.  In the context of the whole application, the snippet provided by acw1668 is actually how it needs to be implemented (which is why it's marked as answered).  My mistake was one of syntax, not design.  Thanks again for your help!